# Where to use json_encode() and make this AJAX request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I have to authenticate the user using a `getthedb.php` file which should receive data in JSON format (done using `json_encode()` function). This should send response again in JSON format. I want to use this structure that I have made and also a callback function which I don't know how to write and use. This username and password should be `json_decode()` in the `getthedb.php` file and username and password can be matched to the entries in the database. On success it should redirect the to the home page.

```
    function checkPassword()
       {    
    var username = $("#username").val();
    var password =$("#password").val();

    $.ajax({
        url: "/getthedb.php",
        type:"POST",
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: JSON.stringify(userdetails),
        success: function mycallback() 
            {

                alert("hi");    
            }
    });

        }

          </script>
          <body>

      <form method="post">
    <label for="username">Username: </label>
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Username" 
            required />
    <label for ="password">Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password"
             required />
    <button value="Submit" onClick="checkPassword()">Submit</button>
      </form>


             </body>
             </html>
```

I have googled alot and found different methods every time. 
xmlhttp object method not acceptable please. Provide me with some material to study for a good understanding of these ajax requests, where to write these, how to initiate these requests (like in xmlhttp we use `open()`, `setrequestheader()`, `send()` functions). I have just started with these things and really keen to learn to write web services.

Comment: where did the answers and Comments go..??

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to JSON.stringify the data you're sending, just pass in a JSON object, this should appear as an array on the server under the $_POST variable.

Also you don't have a `userdetails` variable. I'd suggest setting the `data` property as

```
data: {
    "username": username,
    "password": password
}
```

These would then come through under $_POST['username'] and $_POST['password']

Comment: Should also note that you want a `return false` at the end of the `onclick` so as to prevent the form from submtting.

A good reference for you would be the jQuery pages (http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)